# Soap Call and __doRequest

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am calling a web service, but I just can not get the answer. I need a special "envelope" so I created one myself and use it to call the web service. This all I have done:

```
$sobre  = '<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
$sobre .= '<Body><cargaTituloElectronicoRequest xmlns="http://ws.web.mec.sep.mx/schemas">';
$sobre .= '<nombreArchivo>' . $arch . '</nombreArchivo>';
$sobre .= '<archivoBase64>' .$xml . '</archivoBase64>';
$sobre .= '<autenticacion><usuario>' . $user . '</usuario><password>' . $pass . '</password></autenticacion>';
$sobre .= '</cargaTituloElectronicoRequest></Body></Envelope>';

$location_URL="https://metqa.siged.sep.gob.mx/met-ws/services/TitulosElectronicos.wsdl";
$action      ="https://metqa.siged.sep.gob.mx/met-ws/services/TitulosElectronicos.wsdl/cargaTituloElectronico";

$client = new SoapClient($location_URL, array('trace' => 1));
try{
        $resultado = $client->__doRequest($sobre, $location_URL, $action, 'SOAP_1_2', 0);
}catch (SoapFault $exception){
    var_dump(get_class($exception));
    var_dump($exception);
    $numLote = 0;
}
echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";
```

I am not recieveing  `__getLastRequest()`, (do not know why)... and "`$action`" I have already used just the method ('`cargaTituloElectronico`') but it does not work.
I can not use `$client->cargaTituloElectronico($params)` because automatically generated envelope is not accepted by the server. 
I would really appreciate your helping me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a solution now. You have to declare a new class extending SoapClient, and then overload the __doRequest method using your own evelope. That's it. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem:

Declare a new class extending SoapClient, and then overload the __doRequest method using your own evelope.

That's it. It worked.